# How to convert newick tree format to tree like Hierarchical javascript object

Tags: javascript, logic

I am currently studying newick format.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format
I have a newick string of a tree

```
(A,B,(C,D)E)F;
```

How to convert this string into a hierarchical javascript object like

```
tree = {
  name: 'F',
  children: [{
    name: 'A'
  }, {
    name: 'B'
  }, {
    name: 'E',
    children: [{
      name: 'C'
    }, {
      name: 'D'
    }]
  }]

}
```

Comment: This question is interesting, but you haven't explained what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work correctly with any input similar to your example.

However, it assumes that each node is identified with a single character. You'd have to modify it to support longer symbols.

Also, this code is not bullet-proof and will break without any warning on invalid input strings.

The main idea is to parse the string in reverse order and keep track of node hierarchy using the *stack* array.

```
var newick = '(A,B,(C,D)E)F',
    stack = [],
    child,
    root = [],
    node = root;

newick.split('').reverse().forEach(function(n) {
  switch(n) {
    case ')':
      // ')' => begin child node
      stack.push(node);
      node = child.children = [];
      break;

    case '(':
      // '(' => end of child node
      node = stack.pop();
      break;

    case ',':
      // ',' => separator (ignored)
      break;

    default:
      // assume all other characters are node names
      node.push(child = { name: n });
      break;
  }
});
```

And here is a simple function that will dump the resulting structure:

```
var dmp;

(dmp = function(node, level) {
  node.forEach(function(n) {
    console.log(Array(level).join('-') + n.name);
    n.children && dmp(n.children, level + 1);
  });
})(root, 1);
```

Output:

```
F
-E
--D
--C
-B
-A
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at taking substrings of the original tree and writing a recursive function that stores the removed letters per heirarchical level.

Possible starter:

```
var str = "Z,I,(A,B,(C,D)E)F,G,H";

var firstClose = str.indexOf("(");
var lastClose = str.lastIndexOf(")");

console.log(firstClose);
console.log(lastClose);

var remainingTree = str.substr(firstClose , lastClose);
console.log(remainingTree);

var lastLetterStr = (str.substring( lastClose + 1 ) );
var lastLetterArray = lastLetterStr.split(',');

var firstLetterStr = str.substring(0,firstClose-1)
var firstLetterArray = firstLetterStr.split(',')

console.log(lastLetterArray);
console.log(firstLetterArray);
```

Apply the same steps to the `remainingTree` string until the string is empty and then create the `tree` object?  You'll have to include some logic so that the function knows how to associate for example `(C,D)` as children of `E` when building up the `time` object

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxabtk18/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [NewickJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newick)

Example:

```
var newick = new Newick('(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F');
```

Or you can use static method:

```
var tree = Newick.parse('(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F');
```

The result:

```
{
    name: "F",
    branchset: [
    {
        name: "A",
        length: 0.1
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        length: 0.2
    },
    {
        name: "E",
        length: 0.5,
        branchset: [
        {
            name: "C",
            length: 0.3
        },
        {
            name: "D",
            length: 0.4
        }]
    }]
}
```

[NewickJS at GitHub](https://github.com/octav47/NewickJS)