# How to convert Newick tree format to a tree-like hierarchical object?

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, tree, logic

I want to convert a [Newick file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format#The_grammar_nodes) to a hierarchical object (similar to what has been posted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310065/how-to-convert-newick-tree-format-to-tree-like-hierarchical-javascript-object)) in Python.

My input is a Newick file like this:

```
(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F:0.9
```

The original post parses the string character by character. To store the branch lengths also, I have modified the JavaScript file (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38311111/5115805)) as follows:

```js
var newick = '// (A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F:0.9',
    stack = [],
    child,
    root = [],
    node = root;

var na = "";
newick.split('').reverse().forEach(function(n) {
    switch(n) {
    case ')':
        // ')' => begin child node
        if (na != "") {
            node.push(child = { name: na });
            na = "";
        }
        stack.push(node);
        child.children = [];
        node = child.children;
        break;

    case '(':
        // '(' => end of child node
        if (na != "") {
            node.push(child = { name: na });
            na = "";
        }
        node = stack.pop();
        // console.log(node);
        break;

    case ',':
        // ',' => separator (ignored)
        if (na != "") {
            node.push(child = { name: na });
            na = "";
        }
        break;

    default:
        // assume all other characters are node names
        // node.push(child = { name: n });
        na += n;
        break;
    }
});

console.log(node);
```

Now, I want to translate this code to Python.

Here's my attempt (I know it's incorrect):

```
class Node:

  def __init__(self):
    self.Name = ""
    self.Value = 0
    self.Children = []

newick = "(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5,G:0.8)F:0.9"
stack = []
# root = []
# node = []

for i in list(reversed(newick)):
  if i == ')':
    if na != "":
      node = Node()
      node.Name = na
      child.append(node)
      na = ""
    stack.append(node)
    # insert logic
    child = node.Children
    # child.append(child)

  elif i == '(':
    if (na != ""):
      child = Node()
      child.Name = na
      node.append(child)
      na = ""
    node = stack.pop()
  elif i == ',':
    if (na != ""):
      node = Node()
      node.Name = na
      node.append(child)
      na = ""
  else:
    na += n
```

Since I am totally new to JavaScript, I am having trouble 'translating' the code to Python. In particular, I didn't understand the following lines:

```
child.children = [];
node = child.children;
```

How can I correctly write this in Python, to also extract the lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments on the JavaScript version:

- It has some code repetition (`if (na != '') ...`) which is easy to avoid.
- It uses `node` as variable name for an array. Readability is improved when you use a plural word for arrays (or lists in Python).
- It does not output what you want to have: it outputs nodes with names like "9.0:F", not isolating the length from the name.

Because of the last point, the code needs first to be corrected before making the translation into Python. It should support splitting the name/length attributes, allowing either of them to be optional. Additionally, it could assign id values to each created node and add a `parentid` property to refer to a node's parent.

I personally prefer coding with recursion instead of using a stack variable. Also, with a regular expression API you can easily tokenise the input to facilitate the parsing:

#### JavaScript version of Newick format parser

```js
function parse(newick) {
    let nextid = 0;
    const regex = /([^:;,()\s]*)(?:\s*:\s*([\d.]+)\s*)?([,);])|(\S)/g;
    newick += ";"
    
    return (function recurse(parentid = -1) {
        const children = [];
        let name, length, delim, ch, all, id = nextid++;;

        [all, name, length, delim, ch] = regex.exec(newick);
        if (ch == "(") {
            while ("(,".includes(ch)) {
                [node, ch] = recurse(id);
                children.push(node);
            }
            [all, name, length, delim, ch] = regex.exec(newick);
        }
        return [{id, name, length: +length, parentid, children}, delim];
    })()[0];
}

// Example use:
console.log(parse("(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5,G:0.8)F:0.9"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Python version of Newick format parser

```py
import re

def parse(newick):
    tokens = re.finditer(r"([^:;,()\s]*)(?:\s*:\s*([\d.]+)\s*)?([,);])|(\S)", newick+";")

    def recurse(nextid = 0, parentid = -1): # one node
        thisid = nextid;
        children = []

        name, length, delim, ch = next(tokens).groups(0)
        if ch == "(":
            while ch in "(,":
                node, ch, nextid = recurse(nextid+1, thisid)
                children.append(node)
            name, length, delim, ch = next(tokens).groups(0)
        return {"id": thisid, "name": name, "length": float(length) if length else None, 
                "parentid": parentid, "children": children}, delim, nextid

    return recurse()[0]

# Example use:
print(parse("(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5,G:0.8)F:0.9"))
```

About the assignment `node = child.children` in your JavaScript code: this moves the "pointer" (i.e. `node`) one level deeper in the tree that is being created so that in the next iteration of the algorithm any new nodes are appended at that level. With `node = stack.pop()` that pointer tracks back one level up in the tree.

Comment: @trincot- Your solution is perfect. It's very elegant. Thanks for all the clarifications too. I would even like to get the index of a child's parent for every node. For e.g., given- (A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4):0.5), the output should be a result dictionary like- result['name'] = ['A', 'B', 'CD', 'C', 'D'], result['value'] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4] and result['parent'] = [-1, -1, -1, 2, 2] where parent contains index of a node's parent's position from result['name']. How can your code be modified so it outputs a dictionary with name, value, parent instead of a list? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, this is honestly well beyond the question you asked. In this example the name of the 4th node is a derivation of nodes C and D, which differs from what you put in the question. If you need help with that, I suggest you create a new question dedicated to that.

Comment: Well, I felt like doing it anyway: I updated my answer with code that parses any Newick compatible strings and adds a `parentid` and `children` properties to each node. Enjoy!

Comment: @trincot- Thanks a lot for all the help. Your current javascript code provides the exact output that I need (one small bug-it fails to provide name and length values for root element). However, I need to implement this in python. The python version fails to provide the correct tree structure. The strings I tried are here-https://gist.github.com/chaityacshah/f79f36bd48937663762191fa82e93d10. I have been trying to modify your code but have been unable to do so. Can you please help with the correct python version? Thanks again!

Comment: Corrected that. The JS version did not add the ";" delimiter at the end if it was missing (in my understanding the newick format requires it). The Python version had a `pop()` where it should have been `pop(0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I wanted. Will create 1-d arrays now for `name`, `parentid` and `length`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code might not be an exact translation of the javascript code, but it works as expected. There were some issues like "n" to be not defined. I also added the parsing of the node name into name and value, and a parent field.

You should consider using already existent parsers like https://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo as they already give you the infrastructure and algorithms to work with the trees.

```
class Node:
    # Added parsing of the "na" variable to name and value.
    # Added a parent field
    def __init__(self, name_val):
        name, val_str = name_val[::-1].split(":")
        self.name = name
        self.value = float(val_str)
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    # Method to get the depth of the node (for printing)
    def get_depth(self):
        current_node = self
        depth = 0
        while current_node.parent:
            current_node = current_node.parent
            depth += 1
        return depth

    # String representation
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}:{}".format(self.name, self.value)

newick = "(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5,G:0.8)F:0.9"

root = None
# na was not defined before.
na = ""
stack = []
for i in list(reversed(newick)):
    if i == ')':
        if na != "":
            node = Node(na)
            na = ""
            if len(stack):
                stack[-1].children.append(node)
                node.parent = stack[-1]
            else:
                root = node
            stack.append(node)

    elif i == '(':
        if (na != ""):
            node = Node(na)
            na = ""
            stack[-1].children.append(node)
            node.parent = stack[-1]
        stack.pop()
    elif i == ',':
        if (na != ""):
            node = Node(na)
            na = ""
            stack[-1].children.append(node)
            node.parent = stack[-1]
    else:
        # n was not defined before, changed to i.
        na += i

# Just to print the parsed tree.
print_stack = [root]
while len(print_stack):
    node = print_stack.pop()
    print(" " * node.get_depth(), node)
    print_stack.extend(node.children)
```

The output of the print bit at the end is the following:

```
 F:0.9
  A:0.1
  B:0.2
  E:0.5
   C:0.3
   D:0.4
  G:0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pyparsing parser for this input string. It uses pyparsing's `nestedExpr` parser builder, with a defined content argument so that the results are parsed key-value pairs, not just simple strings (which is the default).

```
import pyparsing as pp
# suppress punctuation literals from parsed output
pp.ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(pp.Suppress)

ident = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
value = pp.pyparsing_common.real

element = pp.Group(ident + ':' + value)
parser = pp.OneOrMore(pp.nestedExpr(content=pp.delimitedList(element) + pp.Optional(','))
                      | pp.delimitedList(element))

tests = """
    (A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F:0.9
"""
parsed_results = parser.parseString(tests)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(parsed_results.asList(), width=20)
```

Gives:

```
[[['A', 0.1],
  ['B', 0.2],
  [['C', 0.3],
   ['D', 0.4]],
  ['E', 0.5]],
 ['F', 0.9]]
```

Note that the pyparsing expression for parsing reals also does parse-time conversion to Python floats.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python library `bigtree` that does this out-of-the-box for you with one line of code.

```py
from bigtree import newick_to_tree
newick_str = "(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F:0.9"

# Create the tree
root = newick_to_tree(newick_str, length_attr="length")

# Visualize the tree
root.show(attr_list=["length"])
```

This will result in the output

```
F [length=0.9]
├── A [length=0.1]
├── B [length=0.2]
└── E [length=0.5]
    ├── C [length=0.3]
    └── D [length=0.4]
```

Hope this helps!

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `bigtree` :)